# array address addition in MIPS and translating to C

Tags: mips

I just started learning MIPS and don't have much idea what's going on. The following problem asks to translate the last add instruction to C code :

```
    .data
      A:        .word    0:16         # in C: int A[16];
.text
      la        $s6,    A             # in C: int* s6 = A;
      li        $t0,    3             # in C: int t0 = 3; // integer array index
      sll       $t0,    $t0,  2       # (In MIPS: $t0 = $t0 << 2)  ($t0*4 is the byte offset used in MIPS.)   
      add       $s0,    $s6,  $t0     # <--- What is the equivalent C code
```

What I understood was this : the address of array A is stored in register $s6, then the constant 3 denoting an array index is stored in $t0, the sll instruction stores 3*2^2 = 12 into register $t0. Then, the add instruction adds the contents of $s6 and $t0 and stores the sum into $s0.

$s6 + $t0 = address of A + 12 ?? I am not able to make sense of this, please help me? Does it mean it adds 12 to the address of A and stores that into $s0?

Comment: The equivalent C code would be `s6 = s6 + 3`. Since you already declared `int* s6` the 3 is understood to be multiplied by `sizeof(int)`. Assembly doesn't do this for you, hence the times 4 that it does.

Answer (score 0):

In C, we do array indexing as follows:

```
a[i]
```

which by definition of the operators in C is equivalent to

```
*(a+i)
```

This construct represents pointer arithmetic (pointer addition, with binary `+` operator), followed by dereference (the unary `*` operator, applied after the addition).

What you're showing is just the pointer arithmetic without the dereference, so basically:

```
a+i
```

C knows which one is the pointer and which one is the index, so even `i+a` would be the same in C (we can also do `*(i+a)` and `i[a]` in C, believe it or not, and these are both equivalent to `a[i]` and `*(a+i)`, indexing into the array to access an element.)

The fundamental difference here between C and assembly (beyond syntax) is that C knows the data type of the pointer, and so automatically scales the index by the element size and you never see that explicitly done in C — whereas in assembly it must be done explicitly, which is `sll` (shift of two) being used to multiply the index by 4.

So the addition of the array base pointer and index in C is more or less formally called pointer arithmetic and is equivalent to the shift and add in assembly.  Since C hides the scaling, though, there's no direct equivalent to just the add alone.

In C, pointer arithmetic also includes subtraction of pointer and index, with the same scaling automatically applied to the index.

In C, pointer arithmetic also include subtraction of two pointers, so `a-b` if they are both pointers to the same type and same array or memory block, will compute the index that represents the difference between two pointers.  In C, this is also inversely scaled to obtain a regular index.  In assembly we can do the same with subtraction followed by shifting in the opposite direction, namely right.

Of course there is no addition of pointer to pointer (it doesn't make sense).

---

Most hardware these days is byte addressable, so we need to use byte addressing both in C and in assembly.  (In languages like Java that don't have pointers we don't see the byte addressing that the language does for you, much like C hides index scaling.)

Any pointer is, in some sense, a pointer to a single byte.  Data items that occupy more than one byte are referred to by their first byte, and this  includes arrays, structs, etc..

To do array indexing (into an integer array) we convert the index (0,1,2,3) into a byte offset (0,4,8,12) by scaling (multiplying the index by the pointer's element size).  Then add the byte address (base of the array) to that byte offset, yielding another byte address, but this one refers to the element at the index.